# Export text file to excel using python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, xlwt

**I have some text files & I need to convert that file into excel format. **

[Txt_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6kDT.png) ,
[Txt_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOMuJ.png)

*I'm using Python Pandas to do it. But I'm getting output as this *
[Converted_excel_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Vz1.png)

*After converting data is not in proper order*

```
*Code..*
import pandas as pd
my_cols = [str(i) for i in range(20)] # create some row names
df = pd.read_table('TEST_1.txt',                                  
                                sep='\s+[\s|\r]',                   
                                skip_blank_lines=False,
                                skipinitialspace=True,
                                names=my_cols,                               
                                engine="python")
df.to_excel('Converted_excel_file.xlsx' )
```

*How to Convert Txt file in proper way using Pandas or xlwt ,Openpyxl ??*

Comment: What do you mean by "not in the proper order" - how are we supposed to know what the right order is? Can you please explain more clearly.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood when I converted Txt_1 file I got result see Converted_excel_file, All data in mismatched in all columns its not like Txt_1 file

Comment: ok got it - I think the problem, in part, is due to your separator, there seems to be cross-contamination with it along columns. Have you tried read_csv instead of read_table?

Comment: @HaydenEastwood Yeah ! I tried with 'read_table' & with read_fwf but the result is same.

Comment: Can you provide an actual text sample so that I can try to replicate your issue and fix it?

Comment: @HaydenEastwood Yeah ! Sure.  download file from this  [link](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/n06imtyy1agtj/Test_data)

Comment: You'd be much better off writing you're own code to convert these files to rows that you can feed to openpyxl.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood okay !... I'll check openpyxl.   right now  I'm Trying Different method in python in that i'm getting 95% accuracy of proper data ..